# Select columns(two columns) in sub query in select clause with custom column name(using AS)

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

Select columns(two columns) in sub query in select clause with custom column name(using AS)..

```
SELECT a, b,

      (SELECT t.column1,
              t.column2
       FROM table1 t
       WHERE COLUMN_NAME =
         SELECT (MAX(columnname))
         FROM table1))AS c, AS d
    From table3
```

Comment: Sample data, expected results, and your attempts (as this is clearly pseudo-SQL) are really going to be needed here for us to help you.

Comment: use `OUTER APPLY` not a subquery in the `SELECT`. Subqueries in the `SELECT` must return a single column. or write it as a join if possible

Comment: It'll also be helpful if you ask a question as well. All, you have done here is make a statement(demand) in your title, copied it into the body of your question, and pasted it, and then provided an invalid SQL Statement (for several reasons).

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the subquery inside a CTE and cross join to the table:

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT column1 AS c, column2 AS d
  FROM table1
  WHERE COLUMN_NAME = (SELECT MAX(COLUMN_NAME) FROM table1)
)
SELECT t3.a, t3.b, t.c, t.d
FROM table3 t3 CROSS JOIN cte t
```